# Subnetting Difficulty

Tags: networking, hosts, subnet, broadcast

[image]

[image]

Taking the following example shown in the first image, why has my teacher has assigned in the solution (image 2) for network one (N1): 7+2 hosts?

Shouldn't it be 6+2 since the number of hosts in that network is 6 and the first and the last (broadcast) can't be assigned?

He has done the same things until N6 and N7 where he assigned 2+2 for the link.

Is this correct and there should be something that I need to know?

Comment: Did you ask your teacher for an explanation? What was his answer?

Comment: The courses are over and unfortunately he's not replying at my email.

Comment: My guess is that the router deserves an ip address too. #hosts + router + boardcasts = #hosts + 3. This explains the given solution and is coherent with picture 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Router R1's interface to network N1 requires an IP address in network N1's range.  That is the 7th IP address.  You can see the same one-more-than-listed on N2, N3, and N4.

N6 has two hosts -- R5 and R3.  Same for N7.